# Deleted file when i execute the "sass --watch ..." command

Tags: css, sass

I'm working on a Ionic project (Ionic 2.1.0, node 7.0.0, cordova 8.0.0) and when I want to change the style, I execute the command :

> sass --watch www/scss/ionic.app.scss:www/scss/ionic.app.csss

After this, the cli write :

> Deleted www/scss/ionic.app.css. Error: compound selectors may longer
>   be extended. Consider `@extend .ion-load-a, :before` instead. See
>   "an url" for details.
>
> @extend .#{$ionicons-prefix}load-a:before;
>             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   www\lib\ionic\scss\ionicons_ionicons-animation.scss 51:11  root
>   stylesheet
>
> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.

So, the style is broken. Any idea ?

Comment: Reading that error message, it seems to me it's telling you that your scss is invalid and it can't generate the css. I've never used the `--watch` switch myself, but my understanding is that it is supposed to replace the indicated css file with the one it generates, so it makes sense it deletes an existing file.

Comment: We are many people who worked on this file, and no problems on other people.... I think it's a configuration problem...

Comment: You didn't provide your configuration and theirs, so we can't really help you with that, can we?